# Do anyone know how to Multiple N Odd Number Using Assembly x86 Language?

Tags: assembly, x86

Do anyone know how to Multiple N Odd Number Using Assembly x86 Language that using MUL mnemonic
Ex : SUM=1*3*5*7*..........*n

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Look up any factorial loop and change it to increment by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Why do you want to use one-operand `mul ecx`, instead of something like `imul eax, ecx` which is at least slightly more efficient (https://agner.org/optimize/)?  Do you want extended-precision with a result that's wider than a register?  And BTW, `mul` isn't a "keyword", it's an instruction mnemonic.

Comment: Yes there was a typo in my question but it already been edited. English is not my first language and I never use stackoverflow before ,this is my first time.

Comment: The reason I don't use IMUL , because I only knew afew mnemonic such mov,add,sub and mul.

Comment: `mul` is not a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply numbers with the `MUL` instruction you put one number in `eax` (or `rax` or `ax` depending on operand size) and another number somewhere else (in any other register or in memory), then do `MUL` and expect the result in `edx:eax` (or `rdx:rax` or `dx:ax`).

For example (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov eax,1      ;eax = 1
    mov ebx,2      ;ebx = 2
    mov ecx,5      ;ecx = 5
    mul ebx        ;edx:eax = 1 * 2
    mul ecx        ;edx:eax = (1 * 2) * 5
```

Of course when they're constants you can cheat and let the assembler do it when the code is assembled. For example (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov eax,1*2*5*7
```

You can also do the `MUL` in a loop. For example, if the values come from a table or array (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov eax,[table]
    mov esi,table+4
    mov ecx,31-1            ;31 items in table?
.next:
    mul dword [esi]         ;edx:eax = temp * table[i]
    add esi,4
    loop .next
```

However, if there's some sort of relationship between the values you don't need a table. Your sequence seems wrong to me and I suspect you actually wanted "`1*3*5*7 ... N`" (and suspect that the `2` was a typo), and "`1*3*5*7 ... N`" is a sequence that can be done without a table. For example (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov ecx,31          ;ecx = N = 31
    mov ebx,1           ;ebx = the value the result was multiplied with last
    mov eax,1           ;eax = the result
.next:
    lea ebx,[ebx+2]     ;ebx = the value to multiply with the result next
    mul ebx             ;edx:eax = new current result
    cmp ebx,ecx         ;Has N been reached?
    jb .next            ; no, keep going
```

Note that you can cheat to improve performance. For example, you can do something like this (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov ecx,31          ;ecx = N = 31

    mov eax,1           ;eax = the current result
    mov ebx,1           ;ebx = the value the result was multiplied with last
    cmp ecx,9           ;Is the last value greater than 9?
    jle .next           ; no, don't cheat
    mov eax,1*3*5*7*9   ; yes, cheat by skipping the first 4 multiplications
    mov ebx,9           

.next:
    lea ebx,[ebx+2]     ;ebx = the value to multiply with the result next
    mul ebx             ;edx:eax = new current result
    cmp ebx,ecx         ;Has N been reached?
    jb .next            ; no, keep going
```

You can cheat a lot more using a pre-computed lookup table. For example (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov ecx,31                      ;ecx = N = 31
    mov eax,[resultTable + ecx*4]   ;eax = result for N
```

Of course you can halve the size of the table like this:

```
    mov ecx,31                      ;ecx = N = 31
    shr ecx,1                       ;ecx = N/2 = 15
    mov eax,[resultTable + ecx*4]   ;eax = result for N
```

You can also build the table at run time, effectively turning it into a kind of cache:

```
    mov ecx,31                         ;ecx = N = 31

    mov edx,ecx                        ;edx = N
    shr edx,1                          ;edx = N/2
    cmp dword [resultTable + edx*4],0  ;Is the result for this N already known?
    je .unknown                        ; no, have to calculate it
    mov eax,[resultTable + edx*4]      ; yes, just use the result from last time
    jmp .done

.unknown:
    mov eax,1                          ;eax = the current result
    mov ebx,1                          ;ebx = the value the result was multiplied with last
    cmp ecx,9                          ;Is the last value greater than 9?
    jle .next                          ; no, don't cheat
    mov eax,1*3*5*7*9                  ; yes, cheat by skipping the first 4 multiplications
    mov ebx,9           

.next:
    lea ebx,[ebx+2]                    ;ebx = the value to multiply with the result next
    mul ebx                            ;edx:eax = new current result
    cmp ebx,ecx                        ;Has N been reached?
    jb .next                           ; no, keep going

    shr ecx,1                          ;ecx = N/2
    mov [resultTable + edx*4],eax      ;Store the result for next time

.done:
```

However, any previous result for a lower value of `N` can be used as a starting point to calculate the result for any higher value of `N`. This leads to the following approach (32-bit, NASM syntax, untested):

```
    mov ecx,31                    ;ecx = N = 31

    shr ecx,1                     ;ecx = N/2
    mov ebx,[highestN2]           ;ebx = the highest N/2 that's been done before
    cmp ecx,ebx                   ;Has this N/2 been done before?
    ja .unknown                   ; no
    mov eax,[resultTable + ecx*4] ; yes, use the previously calculated result
    jmp .done

.unknown:
    mov eax,[resultTable + ebx*4] ;eax = highest result previously calculated
.next:
    inc ebx                       ;ebx = next N/2 to use
    lea edx,[ebx*2+1]             ;edx = next N to use
    mul edx                       ;edx:eax = old result * N
    mov [resultTable + ebx*4],eax ;Store it for later
    cmp ebx,ecx                   ;Have we done enough?
    jb .next                      ; no, keep going
    mov [highestN2],ebx           ;Set the new highest N/2 calculated so far

.done:
```

Comment: Surprised you didn't mention that one-operand `mul` (3 uops on Haswell) is less efficient than `imul eax, ebx` (1 uop on basically everything).  https://agner.org/optimize/.  Using `mul` is a totally artificial constraint that makes the code slower, and is only useful if you actually want the high-half result.  Also, using two accumulators would let you run two dependency chains in parallel, doing `1*5*9*13*...` and `3*7*11*15*...`, and multiplying the two at the end.  Since `imul` has at least 3 cycle latency, this will double your throughput for large `n`.

Comment: (And since we avoid even numbers, large `n` don't just result in the low 32 bits being all zero.  So the modular result is potentially interesting.)

Comment: Your memoization/cache approach is interesting, but you're complicating the code by insisting on keeping an index in `ebx`.  If you instead keep `idx*2 + 1` in EBX (i.e. the thing you want to multiply by), then you're all set to use `add ebx, 2` / `imul eax, ebx` / `mov [resultTable + ebx*2 - 2], eax`.  And you can use EDX instead of EBX.  There's also no reason to use `lea` instead of `add` here; on Intel CPUs you're just creating more potential for resource conflicts on port 1 where the integer multiply unit is.  Maybe if you're tuning for in-order Atom?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Realistically; for 32-bit this is probably going to overflow for `N >= 13`, and if it's only going to work for small `N` a pre-calculated table (e.g. with no more than 7 entries maybe?) is going to be smaller and easier than having code. The same applies to 64-bit (only good for `N <= 20`?). To make having code sane you'd need something significantly larger (e.g. 1024-bit integers). In other words; `IMUL` (which OP didn't ask about) isn't very useful for any practical case.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Heh - the example code is example code (existing for no reason other than to illustrate a concept, with no real reason to optimise it and no real reason to care if it's correct or full of bugs).

Comment: The result modulo 2^32 is possibly interesting.  It's not all zeros because we've excluded powers of 2.  So large `n` is possibly interesting.  I don't see what that has to do with `imul` vs. `mul`, though.  You always want 2-operand `imul` unless you're optimizing for code-size and clobbering EDX doesn't hurt overall, or if you do want to use the high-half result.  `imul r32, r/m32` is the normal x86 way to do a 32x32-bit => 32-bit multiply, that's why compilers use it. The legacy one-operand full-multiply instructions are only needed in rare special cases, ever since 2-operand imul was added

Comment: @PeterCordes: Sure, but like I said, the "rare case" (e.g. needing the higher 32-bits in EDX to implement a 1024-bit multiply) is the only case that makes sense for `1*3*5*7... ` in practice, and the only case where you can actually use `IMUL` in practice is a case where you shouldn't use any code at all.

Comment: @Brendan: i just write my own solution . so can u look at it and give me some comment. `MUL AX,1    ; MUL BX,1 ;  MOV CX,10 // Suppose that my n is 10 ; .While(CX!=0);  MUL BX ; Add BX,2 ; Dec CX;​ .endw;`

Comment: @Panha: I think you meant `mov ax,1; mov bx,1`. The `.While(CX!=0)` won't work (too high level) and (if N is never zero) could be a `jne .next` immediately after the `dec cx` (so that you can avoid an extra comparison by using the flags from the decrement)

Comment: @Brendan :sorry there was so many typo. in the code that I write , MUL bx (does that mean ebx=ax*bx,. while (cx!=0) is what I was taught at school.

Comment: @Panha: `mul bx` is `dx:ax = bx * ax`. If you know the result will fit in 16 bits you can ignore the higher half of the 32-bit result in `dx` and only use the lower half of the result in `ax`. Of course (assuming N must be an odd positive number) there's only 6 possible values of N (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11) where the result will fit in 16 bits.